# Could anyone explain the derivation of $\epsilon$ in these proofs.

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the proof to a problem I was doing. The problem states: "Show that if $s_n\ge a$ for all but finitely n, then $\lim s_n\ge a$.

Here are two proofs for this problem.

Assume, for a contradiction, that $\lim s_n=s<a$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{a−s}{2}$. Then, there exists $N$ so that $n > N$ $\Rightarrow$
$|s_n − s|<\epsilon= \frac{a−s}{2}$. Hence, for all $n > N$ we have $s_n < a$, i.e., for all but finitely many $n$, $s_n < a$, a contradiction.$\square$

The other proof is: . Consider the set ${k : s_k < a}$. By assumption, this set is finite. Therefore, it has a
maximum, $M$.
Now, suppose that $\lim s_n = s < a$. By definition of limit, for any  $\epsilon> 0$, there exists $N_0 ∈ \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N_0$ implies $|s_n − s| <\epsilon $. So, pick  $\epsilon= a − s > 0$ and let $N_0$ be the corresponding natural number.
Define $N := \max[N_0, M]$. Then we have that for all $n \geq N$, both of the following
are true:
$s_n ≥ a$

$|s_n − s| < a − s$

Expanding the absolute value, we see that $s − a < s_n − s < a − s$ for all $n \geq N$. But this
implies$ s_n < a$ for all $n ≥ N$, which is a contradiction.$\square$

I am having trouble in understanding as to how each $\epsilon$ was determined. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about proofs that often goes unmentioned in math books is that, while the presentation is logically sound, they often sweep under the rug a lot of scratch work that goes into thinking up the proof.

Suppose we're thinking about the first problem. We've set up an assumption to contradict, namely that $a>s$. The definition of a limit tells us that all but finitely many $s_n$ are contained in the interval $(s - \epsilon,s + \epsilon)$ for *any* $\epsilon > 0$. We want to use this to contradict our assumption that all but finitely many lie above $a$, one easy way would be if all of that interval lay below $a$. So we really just want to chose $\epsilon$ such that $s+ \epsilon \leq a$, because then if $s_n < s+\epsilon$ we know $s_n < a$. Probably for visualization reasons they chose to take $\epsilon$ to only get halfway up from $s$ to $a$ (that is, $\epsilon = \frac{a-s}{2}$). Technically the whole thing works if you set $\epsilon = a-s$, but the halfway makes a nice picture.